# Attach different CSS classes to first and second link

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have a Paragraph type 'Call to action' with one link field `field_link`.

I have another Paragraph type where I call the 'Call to action' paragraph as an `Entity reference revisions` field. With `Allowed number of values` set to **2**.

So the editor is able to insert two Call to action links.

I want to attach **2** specific CSS classes to both links:

On the first link:

```
<a href="" class="button-one">Button one</a>
```

On the second link:

```
<a href="" class="button-two">Button two</a>
```

How do I loop through, so I am able to attach different classes?

**Update:**

In `paragraph--call-to-action.html.twig` I added:

{% block paragraph %}

{% for item in content.field_link %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
      Button one
    {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
      Button two
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock paragraph %}

But now it's rendering always the 2 buttons? What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured how to loop through an entity reference field. Because I am looping from inside a paragraph twig through another paragraph (entity reference) I have to loop the children:

```
{% for item in content.field_name|children %}
```

So the `children` did the trick! Then you can do something like:

```
{% set link_class = loop.index == 1 ? 'primary' : 'secondary' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom twig template to the call to action paragraph type.

Some code like this might work:

```
{% for item in content.field_link %}
  {% if loop.index == 1 %}
    {% set class == 'button-one' %}
  {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
    {% set class == 'button-two' %}
  {% endif %}
  <a class="{{ class }}" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

When creating a for loop in twig you always have the `loop.index` available.
Loop.index is 1 indexed thats why you have to check if index is 1 or 2.

Comment: If you only want the custom buttons some places you can maybe add a checkbox to the field, that you can check if you want custom fields, and then check for the field in twig.

Comment: No this is not the case. It should be possible with an index or loop or something isn't it? I have a Paragraph type (Slide) where you can insert a Title, image and one, or two buttons! The buttons are the `Entity reference revisions field` from the Paragraph type Call to action (with one field `field_link`). The first link should get `class="button-one"` and the second button should get `class="button-two"`

Comment: I have updated my code, try that.

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95735/discussion-between-jdrupal-and-meez).

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting the number of links via the Drupal UI, plus you don't have to style `instance99` if you had more than two links.

I would keep it simple.

**Twig**:

```
{% for item in content.field_link %}
  <a href="" class="button instance{{ loop.index }}">
    Button one
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

**Styles**:

```
a.button {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #333;

  &.instance1 {
    color: #444;
  }

  &.instance2 {
    color: #555;
  }
}
```

Adding an additional class will provide better scalability as well.